# unable to upsert using java datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am unable to `upsert` a row using the `datastax` driver.

The data in the Cassandra table is stored like follows:

```
tag        | partition_info
------------+--------------------------------------------------
 sometag | {{year: 2018, month: 1}, {year: 2018, month: 2}}
```

`tag` is primary key and `partition_info` is a UDT

```
CREATE TYPE codingjedi.tag_partitions (
    year bigint,
    month bigint
);
```

I want that if a `tag` doesn't exist then it gets created. If `tag` exists then the new `udt` value gets appended to old one. I suppose I cannot use `insert` as it overrides previous value i.e. this will not work

```
QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName).value("tag",model.tag)
  .value("partition_info",setAsJavaSet(Set(partitionsInfo)))
```

I am trying to use update but  it isn't working. `Datastax` driver gives error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` for following query

```
QueryBuilder.update(tableName).`with`(QueryBuilder.append("partition_info",setAsJavaSet(Set(partitionsInfo)))) 
  .where(QueryBuilder.eq("tag", id.tag))
```

I tried using `add` and `append` for primary key but but got the error `PRIMARY KEY part tag found in SET part`

```
QueryBuilder.update(tableName).`with`(QueryBuilder.add("tag",id.tag))
      .and(QueryBuilder.append("partition_info",setAsJavaSet(Set(partitionsInfo))))           .where(QueryBuilder.eq("tag", id.tag))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the incorrect operation in your update statement - you're using `append`, but it's used to append data to columns of `list` types. You can use instead either `add` if you're adding a single value (your case, so you wont even need to wrap data into `Set` explicitly), or `addAll` if you're adding multiple values.

```
QueryBuilder.update(tableName)
  .`with`(QueryBuilder.add("partition_info", partitionsInfo))
  .where(QueryBuilder.eq("tag", id.tag))
```

Comment: I tried using add but got the error `PRIMARY KEY part tag found in SET part` - `QueryBuilder.update(tableName).`with`(QueryBuilder.add("tag",id.tag))
      .and(QueryBuilder.append("partition_info",setAsJavaSet(Set(partitionsInfo)))) `

Comment: Thanks. Why I had to remove `setAsJavaSet(Set(partitionsInfo))`?

Comment: I thought that you're inserting one value. If you have multiple values there, then just use `addAll(setAsJavaSet(Set(partitionsInfo)))` instead

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't shared all the information. The schema is `CREATE TABLE codingjedi.partitions_of_a_tag (
    tag text PRIMARY KEY,
    partition_info set<frozen<tag_partitions>>
)`. As `partition_info` is a set of the `UDT`, I was doing `setAsJavaSet(Set(partition_info))` even though I was inserting only one value. Removing that and using add made it work. I understood the logic of `add` but don't understand why I had to also remove `setAsJavaSet(Set...))`.

Comment: you need to remove it because you're appending single element that is just UDT, not the set of UDTs